# Removing a file or folder using VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I bring up VS Code I see options for adding a file or folder but I do not see options to delete a file or folder or rename such. Any hints?

Comment: Have you tried the del key?

Answer (score 6):

Deleting file is strait forward. To delete a folder created using MS Code explorer,

1. press Ctrl + Shift + P then  it will show a command prompt like
   section at top.
2. Search 'remove' in that. A command will be shown -"Workspaces: Remove folder from workspace...". Click on that.
3. Intended folder name will be shown for removing.
4. After clicking the same, it will be removed from explorer, without affecting actual
   files on the operating file system.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you I figured it out. It doesn't seem immediately obvious to me but on a MAC using VSCode selecting a file and entering the return key lets you rename a file, selecting a file and then using command-del deletes a file.

Comment: For me, I was right-clicking on the tab which has no `Delete` option. Just had to right-click in the sidebar.

Comment: Pressing command-del deletes a file opened in editor. Don't need to select file from a tree

Answer (score 4):

The `Rename` and `Delete` actions are there, but you have to select the file in the bottom part of Explorer, under the project directory. When you select it under Open Editors or right click on the tab bar, there is no `Delete` and that is confusing. In this case you can choose `Reveal in Side bar` in the tab context menu to get to that entry. But that won't help (will select the tab under Open Editors) if the file is out of the project tree, in this case the most convenient action would probably be to `Open Containing Folder` and delete it manually in the file manager.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Would be nice if there was an option in the command palette.

Answer (score 4):

Using extension:

- Install `File Utils` extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sleistner.vscode-fileutils

- Press `Ctr + Shift + P`
- Type `File Utils > Delete`

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode, make sure you are in `Explorer`. Also make sure you are right-clicking the file shown in the `directory/folder`. Here either hitting `Del` for windows and `command+del` for Mac will delete the file.

A common issue is trying to delete a file when in `source control`. You must be in `explorer`.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.50 (Sept 2020) still has the feature for file deletion, and improves it with [`microsoft/vscode` issue 71315](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71315)

> ##Should maintain row focus after deleting a file
>
> Use case:
>
> - Use the keyboard to focus a file in the explorer and delete it
> - Now the whole tree has focus
> - Press the down arrow key
> - The first item is selected

I want to get back to where I was looking before.

> The search tree **focuses the next item in the list** when one is removed.
> I don't know whether the explorer did this previously with the old tree. But it would be nice for the explorer to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the file or folder you will get the options to delete the file as well as of renaming the file.

Answer (score 0):

For directory delete type in VScode terminal:

```
rm -r directoryName
```

For file delete type in VScode terminal:

```
rm fileName.tx
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your file menu on left top side, then you will see a "close file" option.
Just click on it. your file will be remove from your editor without hamper your original file on your storage.

Comment: That's not what OP is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

No way to delete a folder by a right-click. However, you may remove it from the IDE: **File > Close Folder**.